# Interruption command upon my file

Tags: c++

The file I give you below compiles well and runs but once the « multiplication table » is drawn on the screen, I get the message « interrupted command » and my reading stops.

If I don't use the function «  void table() «  (that's what I did before) the program was not interrupted, but once the program was finished i got a message telling me the stack had difficulties. I should like to make my file run with the function (named « void table() »), as it is now.

I think there is some line to add to my file, in order to stop the interruption. Thank you very much for your help. I should be very happy to have a result.  Now here is my file:

```
 /*essai.cpp*/ 
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
using namespace std; 
bool oui_ou_non() //sous-programme ou "fonction".Suivant votre réponse son data contiendra votre "return" qui est "true" ou "false"                                                 
{ 
    cout << "Oui ou non ?  o/n ?    "; 
    char rep=0; 
    cin >> rep; 
    switch (rep) 
    { 
    case 'o': 
        return true; 
    case 'n': 
        return false; 
    default: 
        cout << "Je prends celà pour un non.\n"; 
        return false; 
    } 
} 
void table() 
{ 
        int array[ 9 ][ 9 ]; // Declares an array that looks like a chessboard 
        for ( int  i = 1; i < 10; i++ ) 
        { 
                for ( int j = 1; j < 10; j++ ) 
                { 
                        array[ i ][ j ] = i * j; // Set each element to a value 
                } 
        } 
        cout << "Multiplication table:\n"; 
        for ( int i = 1; i < 10; i++ ) 
        { 
                for ( int j = 1; j < 10; j++ ) 
                { 
                        cout << array[ i ][ j ] <<" "; 
                } 
        cout << "\n"; 
        } 
} 
//voici deux fonctionss (sous-programmes) où il n'y a aucun return, d'où l'utilisation de void 
void sprog1() 
{ 
cout << "premier  sous-programme (function) où l'on fait qu'imprimer d'où l'utilisation du type void\n"; 
} 
void sprog2() 
{ 
cout << "Bon courage, continuez. \n"; 
} 
int main() 
{ 
cout << "Bonjour\n"; 
sprog1(); 
sprog2(); 
sprog1(); 
sprog2(); 
cout << "Voulez-vous lancer le programme ?\n"; 
bool return_from_function = oui_ou_non();  //dans l'adresse de return_from_function(que vous venez de créer), mettez l'adresse de oui_ou_non 
                                               //les adresses return_from_function et de oui_ou_non contiennent le même data                  
cout << oui_ou_non<<endl; 
cout << return_from_function<<endl; 
cout << "nous sommes revenus au programme principal\n"; 
if ( return_from_function == false ) //si l'adresse de return_from_function contient "false" 
    { 
        cout << "retourné false .  Le programme va s'arrêter.\n"; 
        return 0; 
    }                 //                                                                                                               
    cout << "Programme principal\n"; 
cout << "ARRAYS\n"; 
char  p[]="Zero"; 
p[0]='R'; 
for ( int i(0); i<4; ++i) 
    { 
    cout << p[i]; 
    } 
cout <<endl; 
int v5[8]={11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,}; 
for(int i(0); i<8; ++i) 
    { 
        cout << v5[i] <<" "; 
    } 
cout <<endl; 
cout << "Tapez ENTER pour continuer"; 
cin.ignore(); 
cin.get(); 
cout << "MULTIDIMENTIONNAL ARRAY\n"; 
cout << "Tapez ENTER pour continuer"; 
cin.get(); 
table(); 
cout << "VECTORS, a resizable array\n";  
// N'oubliez pas   #include <vector>   là-haut 
vector<int> a_vector(10); 
cout << "avant l'ajout\n"; 
for ( int i=0; i<10; i++ ) 
 { 
 a_vector[ i ] = 0; 
 cout << a_vector[i] <<" "; 
 } 
 cout << endl; 
//add anew element to the vector 
a_vector.push_back(10); 
cout << "après l'ajout\n"; 
for ( int i=0; i<11; i++ ) 
 { 
 cout << a_vector[i] <<" "; 
 } 
cout <<endl; 
cout << "Tapez ENTER pour continuer"; 
cin.get(); 
cout <<"Aurevoir\n"; 
}
```

Comment: You index an array[9] from 0 to 8, not from 1 to 9.

Comment: @adrianN Why is it UB?

Comment: @Rakete1111 you can't modify string literals.

Comment: @adrianN It's an array `char* p = "Zero"; p[0] = 'R';` would be undefined

Answer (score 2):

Your bug is here :

> ```
>    int array[ 9 ][ 9 ]; // Declares an array that looks like a chessboard 
>    for ( int  i = 1; i < 10; i++ ) 
>    { 
>            for ( int j = 1; j < 10; j++ )
> ```

Your array has 9 elements in each dimention. Thus the valid indices are 0 through 8. *Not* 1 through 9. Counting starts at zero.

Comment: Note: I'm not saying there are no other bugs, but fix that one first.

Comment: In the two cases (use of a function or not) the table is displayed entirely. The interruption occurs at the end of the display of the table, and only in the case I use the function. The file I give you uses the function.

Comment: @sylvain sorry, I have no idea what you are trying to say, nor how it impacts the fact that you index your arrays wrong..? The code you posted has an obvious bug - you assume indices start at 1 while in fact they start at 0. Reading beyond the end of an array (which you do) is undefined behaviour and the compiler can do *whatever* it likes - you can't trust anything. Your program is simply broken.

Comment: I just tried begining with the first being zero. Unfortunately the interrupt is still there.

Comment: Show the code. I have a strong hunch that it's still broken - show us! Your posted code does not exactly inspire confidence that you know what you are doing..